# Replacing Views Query and Displaying Results

Tags: views, database, hooks

I'm relatively new to Drupal and I am working on a view that needs to show both Users and Nodes in the same table. The solution that I have come up with is to use hook_views_pre_execute to replace the view query. However, after I've replaced the query, I just get a table with all blank values. It seems that the fields that I have added have no place to put there data.

This is my very basic test hook_views_pre_execute that I am using to try things out. I will be replacing it with something much more complicated once I get things working:

```
function hook_views_pre_execute(&$view)
{
  if($view->name == 'my_view_name') 
  {
        // Basic setup of the second query.
        $query = db_select('users');
        $query->addField('users','name');
        $view->build_info['query']=$query;
  }
}
```

My view is set up with one field Content: Title which ends up being empty in the table. So how do I add the name column to my table view?

Comment: There's an extremely high chance you don't need custom coding for this.. A lot of experienced people newish to drupal end up coding a lot instead of learning the full capability of views. What's the data structure? How are the nodes and users linked?

Comment: Both users and nodes have a location property that I want to place into a leaflet map via IPGV&M. The users and the nodes should have two separate icons when displayed on the map.  If you have a way to do this, that would be great!